# Smarty Section Making the selected Link Bold

Tags: loops, indexing, selection, smarty, hyperlink

How can I make the selected link from the List below, bold, that you see you are on Page ex. 3 or 5

With this code, If you click on a Link you don't know on which page you are.

The smarty code looks like this;

```
{section name="sitelinks" start=0 loop=$total->sitelinks}
 <span class='tag'>
<a href='/member/{$campaign->id}?start={$smarty.section.sitelinks.index*$limit}&limit={$limit}&sort={$sort}&sortDir={$sortDir}'>
{$smarty.section.sitelinks.index}
</a>
 </span>
 {/section}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. no one answered this question. I realized that there was a var $start. I did

```
{if $start/$limit == 0}<b>{$smarty.section.sitelinks.index}</b>
{else}{$smarty.section.sitelinks.index}{/if}
```

And it worked.